# How can I change the working directory for NUnit tests in Team City?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nunit, teamcity

I am using Team City as the build server, and I have a msbuild build script to build and run integration tests for my project. However, Team City when running my tests decides to ignore the WorkingDirectory attribute on the NUnit task, and as a result my tests fail to initialize:

```
[17:46:54]: [Project "MyProject.msbuild.xml.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (ficc-build target(s)):] C:\dev\BuildAgent\work\30decc96a6997d21\MyProject\MyProject.msbuild.xml Value from NUnit task attribute OutputXmlFile has been ignored because TeamCity NUnit task is used
[17:46:54]: [Project "MyProject.msbuild.xml.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (ficc-build target(s)):] C:\dev\BuildAgent\work\30decc96a6997d21\MyProject\MyProject.msbuild.xml Value from NUnit task attribute WorkingDirectory has been ignored because TeamCity NUnit task is used
[17:46:54]: [Project "MyProject.msbuild.xml.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (ficc-build target(s)):] Value from NUnit task attribute ToolPath has been ignored because TeamCity NUnit task is used
```

How can I force Team City to run these tests from my working directory? I don't want to execute nunit-console directly, because I want to benefit from the built-in reporting on test failures, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way to change TeamCity's working directory using the MSBuild task, but you could take the middle road and use [TeamCity's own console runner](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/TeamCity+NUnit+Test+Launcher), which you could start from within the proper working directory.  Another option is to run the standard NUnit console, with [TeamCity's NUnit Addin](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/TeamCity+Addin+for+NUnit) loaded.